# One master ksh file to call 2 ksh script files

Tags: linux, shell, files, scripting, ksh

I have 2 ksh (korn shell script) : file1.ksh and file2.ksh; and I want to have a master file ksh script that will call the 2 files; what's the code I have to put in  my master file?

Thanks

Comment: Calling the child scripts is just like calling any other external programs.

Comment: I m new in Shell can you give a sample code that will be in the master file please

Answer (score 1):

Take whatever you do to call the two scripts by hand from the command line: perhaps you `cd` to some directory; maybe you run `ksh file1.ksh`, or they are executable: `/path/to/file1.ksh`.

Copy those commands into a file.  This file will be your master shell script.

For example,

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

cd somedir || exit
./file1.ksh
./file2.ksh
```

Note that the "master" script (usually called "a wrapper script") does not have to be written in the same scripting language as the scripts that it is calling. Instead, the script above is written for `/bin/sh`, a shell that is available on most Unix systems.

You may change the first line to `#!/bin/ksh`, or `#!/usr/bin/env ksh` or to whatever you usually use for `ksh` scripts on your system to turn it into a "`ksh` script", but it matters little as the script does not need to use any `ksh`-specific features.

Thes script above will exit if the `cd` fails to change to the wanted directory (where the two scripts are located).